# Debug Android system app?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to create a (root) app in `/system/app`, but having an issue that I can't resolve without seeing some errors and debugging to see exactly where it's going wrong.

If I run from Eclipse, errors are expected however, as the app won't have appropriate permissions.

How can I run a local (`/system/app`) installation, and somehow see what's going wrong?

Can it be done from Eclipse? I had a look at [this](http://andoirddebuganil.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/how-to-debug-android-system-application.html) - but it's so poorly formatted I couldn't make sense of it. If it can't - is there some way to print errors as text?

Comment: Those instructions seem fairly clear, where did you get stuck in following them.  As for the second idea, it is often easier to put meaningful logging in your application and view that and the stack traces of exceptions using the logcat tool or window.  For an app not launched by eclipse you may have to figure out how to disable the filters on the logcat window; personally I prefer to run logcat from the command line.

Comment: But that's my question really - how can I display stuff in logcat if it's running locally, not from Eclipse?

Comment: Use `adb logcat` from the command line, and be prepared to capture the result.  That will depend on your development machine operating system and setup, but it has been covered numerous times in other questions here.